# How to transform a png image into a list of list of RGBA colors?

Tags: python, list, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

I search a way to read a png file and make a 2d matrix of list that represent the color of each pixels in the image.
Something like:

```
import image #image library dosen't exist just for example

myimage = image.load("/document/pycharm_projects/images/pixel_avatar.png") #5x6 px image

size = myimage.size.get() #return (5, 6)
width = size[0]  # 5
height = size[1] # 6

result = []

for y in range(height):
    result.append([])
    for x in range(width):
        pixel_color = myimage.pixel((x, y)).get_rgba() # get the color of the pixel
        result[y].append(pixel_color)
```

to obtain that:

```
[
    ["#00000000", "#000000FF", "#00000000", "#000000FF", "#00000000"],
    ["#00000000", "#000000FF", "#00000000", "#000000FF", "#00000000"],
    ["#00000000", "#000000FF", "#00000000", "#000000FF", "#00000000"],
    ["#00000000", "#00000000", "#00000000", "#00000000", "#00000000"],
    ["#000000FF", "#00000000", "#00000000", "#00000000", "#000000FF"],
    ["#00000000", "#000000FF", "#000000FF", "#000000FF", "#00000000"]
]
```

The example image (100x bigger): [pixel_avatar.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqVhY.png)
How can I do this?

Additional information:
Using the newest version of python 3.7. 
Can be color in this representation `(255, 255, 255, 100)` I don't care.
The result will be transform into a json file.

Comment: What image library are you using? Please tag your question with its name.

Comment: This librairy dosen't exist. It's just an example of what I want. @martineau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the [Pillow fork of the PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) (Python Imaging Library) - which I don't believe for an instance you're not familiar with.

```
from PIL import Image
from pprint import pprint

image_filepath = 'pixel_avatar.png'

print('image file:', image_filepath)
myimage = Image.open(image_filepath)

width, height = myimage.size
print(f'size: {width} x {height}')

pixels = [['#' + bytearray(myimage.getpixel((x, y))).hex() for x in range(width)]
              for y in range(height)]
print('data:')
pprint(pixels)
```

Printed output:

```
image file: pixel_avatar.png
size: 5 x 6
data:
[['#00000000', '#000000ff', '#00000000', '#000000ff', '#00000000'],
 ['#00000000', '#000000ff', '#00000000', '#000000ff', '#00000000'],
 ['#00000000', '#000000ff', '#00000000', '#000000ff', '#00000000'],
 ['#00000000', '#00000000', '#00000000', '#00000000', '#00000000'],
 ['#000000ff', '#00000000', '#00000000', '#00000000', '#000000ff'],
 ['#00000000', '#000000ff', '#000000ff', '#000000ff', '#00000000']]
```

Comment: what pprint do?